# Exception encountered during spring context initialization BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer'

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test, testcontainers, mockmvc

Receiving the below error on running integration tests after migrating spring boot and it's related packages(including `spring-boot-starter-test`) from 2.2.4.RELEASE to 3.1.1.

Error creating bean with name `flywayInitializer` defined in class path resource
[com/freit/medicalservice/config/CustomFlywayConfiguration.class]

```java
@Configuration
class CustomFlywayConfiguration extends FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayConfiguration {
    
    @DependsOn("springContext")
    public FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
       return super.flywayInitializer(flyway, null);
    }
}
```

The error is occuring because SpringContext is null, which could be the result of some miss configuration of flyway or annotations being used in tests.

```
Flywayconfig in .properties file
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration,classpath:/db/test_data,classpath:/db_scripts,com/freit/medicalservice/common/migrations
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.validate-on-migrate=true

Annotations being used in tests files:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
@ActiveProfileTest
```

```
12:33:50.412 [main] ERROR o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - org.flywaydb.core.internal.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLog.error:45 - {  } - Migration of schema `medical_service` to version "1.1.13 - Rename Logo Files To Header Files" failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
12:33:50.458 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh:616 - {  } - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [com/freit/medicalservice/config/CustomFlywayConfiguration.class]: Migration failed !
12:33:50.459 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close:350 - {  } - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
12:33:50.474 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close:352 - {  } - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
12:33:50.513 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger.logMessage:82 - {  } - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
12:33:50.556 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure:824 - {  } - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [com/freit/medicalservice/config/CustomFlywayConfiguration.class]: Migration failed !
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: Migration failed !
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:384)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.lambda$applyMigrations$1(DbMigrate.java:274)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:55)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations(DbMigrate.java:273)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:246)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.lambda$migrateAll$0(DbMigrate.java:141)
    at org.flywaydb.database.mysql.MySQLNamedLockTemplate.execute(MySQLNamedLockTemplate.java:58)
    at org.flywaydb.database.mysql.MySQLConnection.lock(MySQLConnection.java:152)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.lock(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:143)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateAll(DbMigrate.java:141)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:98)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.lambda$migrate$0(Flyway.java:176)
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:204)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Migration failed !
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.java.JavaMigrationExecutor.executeOnce(JavaMigrationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.java.JavaMigrationExecutor.lambda$execute$0(JavaMigrationExecutor.java:54)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DefaultExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultExecutionStrategy.java:27)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.java.JavaMigrationExecutor.execute(JavaMigrationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:376)
    ... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.getBean(java.lang.Class)" because "com.freit.medicalservice.config.SpringContext.context" is null
    at com.freit.medicalservice.config.SpringContext.getBean(SpringContext.java:20)
    at com.freit.medicalservice.common.migrations.V1_1_13__Rename_Logo_Files_To_Header_Files.migrate(V1_1_13__Rename_Logo_Files_To_Header_Files.java:30)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.java.JavaMigrationExecutor.executeOnce(JavaMigrationExecutor.java:62)
    ... 115 common frames omitted



============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

    None


Negative matches:
-----------------

    None


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added @Bean("flywayInitializer") over flywayInitializer() function;

```
@Configuration
class CustomFlywayConfiguration extends FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayConfiguration {
    
    @DependsOn("springContext")
    @Bean("flywayInitializer")
    public FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
       return super.flywayInitializer(flyway, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `CustomFlywayConfiguration` completely, because as far as I understand in declares dependency on `com.freit.medicalservice.config.SpringContext` which is your custom bean, but `FlywayMigrationInitializer` is an infrastructural one. Usually infrastructural beans mustn't depend on custom ones.

If you still need custom initialization order then pat attention, that the problem is about particular field `com.freit.medicalservice.config.SpringContext.context` and not about the bean itself. Maybe you have `Objects.requireNonNull()` in constructor of `com.freit.medicalservice.config.SpringContext`? Try to debug creation of bean `com.freit.medicalservice.config.SpringContext`.